# python log from imported library

Tags: python, logging, import

I am writing a python library `main_lib` that relies on another library `dep_lib` that is installed as dependency.

in both libraries each file starts with :

`logger = logging.getLogger(library_name.filename)`

and logs are done as:

`logger.info("say somthing")`

now in my `main_lib` I have a main method that uses function from both libraries.

I would like logs from both libraries to be printed.  How should I configure the log in this main method?

Comment: Pretty confused about what you mean, could you provide a minimal working example and also provide the desired output&actual output? Or at least provide what did you get as the output for now?

Comment: sorry I have rewritten the question. I can't make minial working example as it requires to create two libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no other code that does something to the logger than they already will print logs to stderr. If no handler is added a handler of last resort will be used, and logs with a level of error or higher will be sent to stderr.

Both handlers and loggers have a setLevel method to set which logs should be handled or ignored. In your case you can fetch the logger in main with `logger = logging.getLogger(library_name.filename)` and call `logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)` or whatever level you want on it. You can also add handlers with `logger.addHandler()`. Also check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial).